# get Screen scale in JavaFX using only public API

Tags: java, svg, javafx-8

I'm trying to make a JavaFX library, that display SVG File as image, work with all Java 8 version:https://github.com/codecentric/javafxsvg

The problem is that it uses the renderScale attributes of java.fx.Screen, which is private and doesn't seem to have direct or indirect accessor in public API.

The value is 1.0f in most case, and can be 2.0f for Retina display on Mac.

```
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.getMaxRenderScale();
```

This gives the value I want, but is in com.sun package so not in public API, and can change (and DO change, see renaming below) between minor versions.

```
com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getRenderScale();
```

Is not in public API and was named getScale() in previous version.

The same renaming for this following accessor whose purpose was to expose the internal attributes!

```
com.sun.javafx.stage.ScreenHelper.getScreenAccessor(Screen).getRenderScale();
// was ScreenHelper.getScreenAccessor(Screen).getScale()  in previous version
```

If I use theses internal API, it can work for the last version: 1.8.0_74, but gives a NoSuchMethodError for certain previous versions (1.8.0_51 for example).

How can i make it work for all java 8 version of the jre?

Note that i tried the naive approach to compute it from dpi, but I should only get rounded value (1.0 or 2.0) and I don't have the rule for the scale computation.

Comment: What do you use such a measure for? Can't the system guess the initial value and let the user configure it?

Comment: Well, this is a good question: the short answer is I forked that library, and just wanted to do a pull request without any structural change. The long answer is that I include the FX Component "Image" without configuring it, because it's an internal JavaFX Component and I don't want to wrap it, and let the scale compute itself for hig-density display. But there is also an hidden question: how to deal with javaFX internal API, and Java SE compatibility breaks?

Comment: the obvious answer to the hidden question: don't use internal api or suffer its bites later on :-) My personal pref is the latter which is not always possible, though

Comment: @kleopatra You are right, this is why I don't like any of my 3 solutions. The problem is I don't see how to provide our own components with this API, since the quantum layer for example is not part of the public API:h ttp://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm

Comment: you might consider posting to the fx dev mailinglist http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev - api can be changed (a bit late in the game for 9, though)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a helper method for myself like this.

```
public static double getRenderScale(Screen screen) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Method m;
    try {
        m = Screen.class.getDeclaredMethod("getScale"); // until 8u60 b15
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        m = Screen.class.getDeclaredMethod("getRenderScale");
    }
    m.setAccessible(true);
    return ((Float) m.invoke(screen)).doubleValue();
}
```

It's a brute force approach but I haven't found anything better.

Comment: It is what thought, but it still uses internal API, just hide it with reflection, and will fail if it is renamed again in the future. we may add another catch with a fallback if none method exists. Adding +1 anyway since it answer to the "how to deal with Java SE compatibility breaks".

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX 9, new public APIs were added to the `Screen` class:

- [`getOutputScaleX()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getOutputScaleX())
- [`getOutputScaleY()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getOutputScaleY())

For the x output scale, the documentation reads:

> Gets the recommended output scale factor of this Screen in the horizontal (X) direction. This scale factor should be applied to a scene in order to compensate for the resolution and viewing distance of the output device. The visual bounds will be reported relative to this scale factor.

Operation is similar for the y output scale.

How the output scale works in practice is described in these related answers:

- [How to make JavaFX tell if I'm on a 4k or 1080p](https://screenhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/74706529/1155209)
- [Controlling UI Scaling on Multiple Monitors with Different Scaling Factors in Swing/JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567031/1155209)